# invalid form on conditiona angularjs

Tags: angularjs

How in angularjs to do what, if myInput==3 , myForm became invalid ?

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FHEQPT5XNZCI

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="">

    <form name="myForm">
        <input type="text" name="myInput" ng-model="myInput" ng-required='!myInput==3'>
    </form>

    <h1>{{myForm.myInput.$valid}}</h1>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use regex and ng-pattern

Comment: What is the point of this form if it only accepts one specific value?

Comment: you can create a directive and use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
!myInput==3
```

This expression will return `false` everytime, since `!myInput` returns a boolean value which will never be equals to `3`.

Change it to this:

```
myInput != 3
```

This will compare `myInput` to `3` actually.

**Edit**:

For validating against a specific value, the easiest way is to use `ng-pattern` directive. If you want to make the input as valid if it contains 3, replace `ng-required` with this:

```
required ng-pattern="/^3$/"
```

This will make the input as required, and will become valid only if it contains the value `3`.

Comment: About `myInput !== 3 is recommended though` - It will not work AFAIK, because the input type is text, and you're trying to compare it to a number

Comment: it not work https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FHEVY2XDD9W0
me need  if you in input enter 3  then form to do invalid

Comment: @User34 -- What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: me need if you in input enter 3 then form to do invalid
ps sorry for my English